# Can I use a .js file for TSLint config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tslint

Choosing a right set of rules, especially for a team of more than 3 members takes a lot of discussion and time. To understand some rules and the necessity of them in every single project members need to try the code with and without it, figuring out what works best.

Thus, it would help a lot to be able to comment out and add hints comments to some rules in the `tslint.json` file but JSON doesn't allow comments.

Even though TSLint seems to work fine with a JSON file with comments, it doesn't look right.

Can I use a .js file, like I would do for other JS libs that support config files in JS/JSON?

Comment: According to [docs](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/05083d5078012f152ed07faebb85be150ab972a7/docs/_posts/2016-03-31-sharable-configurations-rules.md) you should be able to use js files in sharable configs (not sure if it's possible to use them without creating a sharable config). I havent't tried it but maybe you could create a local sharable config with js files and configure tslint to use it as an [npm local module](https://medium.com/@arnaudrinquin/build-modular-application-with-npm-local-modules-dfc5ff047bcc).

Comment: By doesn't look right do you mean in your IDE? You can remap it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even though TSLint seems to work fine with a JSON file with comments, it doesn't look right.

But it is supported for a reason. Other tools in the TypeScript community also support it including the typescript compiler `tsconfig.json`.

## Summary

Use comments in json when its supported

Comment: So seems like they implemented it intentionally? There is no information about it in docs so potentially it can break in the future. Anyway, seems like it's the simplest working solution.